# Scaling CALayer up from bottom. (Not top)

Tags: objective-c, scale, cgrectmake

I have stumbled upon a problem that really shouldn't be too hard to figure out. However, after a lot of trial and error I have still not fount a solution.
I have a CALayer created with CGRectMake(20, 20, 40, 40).
I now want to scale this layer upwards by adding specific values to frame.size.height and frame.size.width, but when I do this, the layer scales downwards.
I have tried modifying the anchorPoint, rotating the layer 180 degrees++, but no luck.
Would love some input on this.

Thanks.

What I want vs What I get:

[image: What I want] 
[image: What I get]

Comment: Have you played with the `geometryFlipped` property on your CALayer?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have experimented with that as well, but no luck!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to modify the y origin of your layer at the same time that you modify the height.  I don't know exactly what your code looks like, but if you're taking the old frame and applying a constant change to the width and height, like this:

```
CGRect newFrame = oldFrame;
newFrame.size.width += kWidthChange;
newFrame.size.height += kHeightChange;
_myLayer.frame = newFrame;
```

then you just need one more line, like:

```
newFrame.origin.y -= kHeightChange;
```

before you reassign the layer's frame.

[image]